# UIStackView can't show UIView when UIView added dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

```
@IBAction func addNewImage(sender: UIButton) {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let myView = UIView(frame: rect)
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    myView.alpha = 1.0
    myStackView.addArrangedSubview(myView)
}
```

This code above is just an action triggered by a button. All I want to do is just add a new `UIView`to the `UIStackView` which is named `myStackView` here, and finally I found the `stackView` re-layout all the `arrangedViews` but the newly added view can't be seen, I don't know why.

Thank you for your great answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let myView = UIView(frame: rect)
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    myView.alpha = 1.0
    myView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(20).active = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(20).active = true
    myStackView.addArrangedSubview(myView)

}
```

It should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer and it really works well, but i still want to know                                                                                                                    why it works with this, i have already declared the width and height of "myView", but why i have to add more ?

Comment: You will have to explicitly provide constraints for UIStackView's subviews leaving aside the frame we specify. Accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Why did you set `constraintEqualToConstant(20)` when he expressed `height` and `width` to `30` in the `CGRect`? Also would it work if having only the anchor setting instead of the rect? Or the rect is also needed for positioning x,y? @satheeshwaran